# Hosting our own calendar, to be shared within a team?

Tags: calendar

I work in a small (3 people) team and we need to be able to share our calendar i.e. to see periods when we are busy/free perhaps to organise meetings and so on.

Outlook and Exchange is not an option.

I know about Google Calendar but I would prefer a tool we can host on our server (preferably PHP + MySQL).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend [Knutsen's WebCalendar](http://www.k5n.us/webcalendar.php) - I've been using it for years.  It's all PHP & MYSQL; completely open source.  It's completely configurable.  Everyone I've suggested to has adopted it.

Comment: WebCalendar is brilliant - exactly what I needed. Thanks Nat !

Comment: Note that WebCalendar does NOT support CalDAV and thus it does not offer real time event updates.
The user has to actually refresh their cal to receive updated events.

Answer (score 13):

I've done a lot of research for my own uses, and I revisit the options every now and then. What I've found is most of the calendaring solutions out there are actually pretty awful. It turns out that shared calendaring is **really hard**.

I originally went with Google Calendar, and I much prefer it. Now I use Google Apps since I got a domain. I like that it is hosted for me so I don't have to deal with the administration of the software and the service. Sure, it might be down sometimes, but I'm getting the service for "free" (advertising and information selling aside :-)). I know of a lot of tech companies with the manpower to setup/build their own solutions that use Google Apps because outsourcing the maintenance to Google frees up their IT staff to add more value.

That said, [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/community/downloads.html) includes a calendaring option in addition to providing email. I would stay away from Microsoft's products and their high priced per-client access, same with any of the large commercial offerings.

Comment: Like the overhead to solve server errors? ;-) http://thenextweb.com/2009/11/10/google-apps-calendars/

Comment: I'm ok with google apps but for Zimbra it's no use, thunderbird with extensions or with sunbird does the same almost ...

Comment: @zillion, how can Sunbird, or any add-on in Thunderbird, do any calendar things without a server that actually *keeps* the calendar items? A clients needs a server, I guess.

Comment: I just compare a little, I have checked a lot "for months" before choosing my own solution ...

Comment: @zillion Sure, I also researched for months and settled on Google Calendar shortly after it was released, and switched to Google Apps when I got my own domain. I've been happy with Google ever since.

Comment: +1 for Google Apps. If you can live with having your data hosted outside your business, it really rocks! Advanced calendar use (calendars for resources like meeting rooms) require Premier Edition though, at $50/user.

Answer (score 3):

The open standard for calendaring is [CalDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) ([RFC4791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791)).  Hopefully you can find a [server and client](http://caldav.calconnect.org/implementations.html) to suit you (also see [DAViCal](http://wiki.davical.org/w/Main_Page) server's [client list](http://wiki.davical.org/w/CalDAV_Clients)).

Comment: Mostly for macs so it's not a good solution for everyone on any operating system ... (Windows,Mac,Linux,Bsd,Solaris - at least)

But I clearly accept that his question is hard and answer it is far more difficult ...

Comment: Apples CalDAV server (Darwin Calendar Server), written in pyhton is cross platform and open source. You can easily find documentation how to install it on your prefered OS on the web.

Answer (score 3):

I also develop apps in php/mysql
I've been checking the answers posted here, and have found another alternative

You could get webcalendar php app, which exports calendar items to RSS
http://www.k5n.us/webcalendar.php

Then, you could get the provider addon for thunderbird, that will allow you to import rss calendars (It works originally with Google Calendar) **or you could just add the calendar rss feed to thunderbird rss feed reader**

Answer (score 3):

Check out [OpenGoo](http://opengoo.org/) - Its kinda like Google Apps, but you can host it yourself. While its not quite comparable to Google Apps, it does meet your requirement of something you can host yourself.

---

**2012-06-05 Update**: Since I'd last posted this OpenGoo has changed their setup and project name. They're now Feng Office, and they've now buried the "host your own" option waaaaayyyyy down on the ["Open Source" page](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/opensource/). You can still host your own, just like before. The options and interface are a little better, but I've long since moved on to other options so I don't know how well the new version works in practice.

Just clarifying since I've been getting some down-votes for "incorrect" information... that was correct when I'd originally posted.

Comment: Not that I mind the down-vote, but why?

Comment: Maybe because you've mentioned Google? ;) +1 because I'd also suggest OpenGoo.

Answer (score 2):

[Darwin CalendarServer](http://trac.calendarserver.org/) with [Mozilla Sunbird](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/sunbird/)?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need email integration?

If not, and you're just after a lightweight PHP app that lets everyone manage the calendar through a browser, then the following might fit the bill:

- [PHP-Calendar](http://www.php-calendar.com)
- [Easy PHP Calendar](http://www.easyphpcalendar.com)

On the other hand if you do need to integrate with email, you will most likely need to use a CalDAV or iCal calendar server.

[DAViCal](http://www.davical.org/) will work with Mozilla, Evolution, Chandler, iCal and iPhone.

Another alternative might be to take a look at some broader CRM packages, as many of these incorporate calendar servers.  This would be a wasteful approach if you have no intention of  using any of the other features, but if you'd get any mileage out of any other CRM'y stuff (contact management, activity management, issue tracking, time tracking, inventory management, etc) then it could work for you.  [Sugar CRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/) seems to be the market leader and is PHP based though I'd recommend taking a look at [OpenCRX](http://www.opencrx.org/).

Comment: +1 for mentioning DAViCal, it does fit the requirements when used with Mozilla Sunbird.

Comment: +1 for the broader package note. Software which manages a calendar only is mostly build for a single user use-case and misses team sharing. »Groupware« is the magic word → most groupwares include calendars with share options and most CRMs include groupwares. Nextcloud, Horde, SOGo, SugarCRM are some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Less is more > http://www.doodle.com/

Comment: But then you'd need to invite all team members to your holidays? The fun of that aside, I doubt Doodle is easily used for that?

Comment: You go once a week put your disponibilities and you could use google calendar or others with it, not so bad after all !!!

I have to coordonate a bulk purchase of 30 persons and that tool help me to choose the best time for all of them for a meeting, just try it a litte you will like it even if it is not perfect, I don't know any better alternative ...

Comment: If it's more useful to know how to use it, you have also options for ok, no and maybe able for meeting ...

http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/doodle/

Answer (score 1):

[Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/)

[Shared-Calendar](http://download.cnet.com/Shared-Calendar/3000-2369_4-10363991.html)

Those two will work

Answer (score -1):

[ZOHO Project Calendar](http://www.zoho.com/projects/projects-calendar.html)

> Zoho Projects calendar is an easy way
>   to securely and quickly organize
>   meetings, events, schedule
>   appointments, manage deadlines and
>   more - all with a simple browser from
>   your desktop. A shared online  project
>   calendar is easy for the entire team
>   to stay on schedule, remind the team
>   on upcoming events and make everyone
>   in the project more productive.
>
> Schedule group meetings and events for
>   your entire team. You can see who is
>   available instantly and schedule your
>   conference room and other resources.
>   Set permissions, provide access to
>   members to view a scheduled meeting on
>   a group calendar.
>
> Share your project calendar with your
>   team or coworkers or clients. Provide
>   editing rights and see shared events
>   alongside their own schedules, while
>   securing the access of your personal
>   appointments.

[image]

Comment: This is not a self-hosted calendar as requested by the OP.